# can't run my laravel app on windows through vagrant

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I'm following larcast tutorials for up and running laravel i have setup the laravel its working fine now i wanted it through vagrant on my windows.
But i can't run my app when ever i browse "**todo.app:8000**" the pages doesn't response and displays the message "**web page not avaliable**".
 
however when i was setting it up on the first time i could access the page through "**localhost:8000**" and i was accessing it without "**php artisan serve**" command, but couldn't with "**todo.app:8000**" after that i updated composer and restarted machine and things gone even worst now i can't even access it with "**localhost:8000**" while if i run "**php artisan serve**" it works right. 
Also there is no error on running homestead,vagrant or laravel commands they are working just fine.
 Can anyone please tell what i'm doing wrong ?
This is my homestead.yml file

```
---

ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
- map: todo.app
  to: /home/vagrant/code/learning-laravel-5/public

databases:
- homestead
variables:
- key: AAP_ENV
value: local
# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

These are the configuration i have done in windows host file

```
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
    #
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 todo.app
127.0.0.1 mynew.app
```

If anything else is needed then please tell that also. I have already spent whole day in figure it out but i'm stuck here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points to address (1 and 2 should fix your issue):

1. you cannot have todo.app point to your `127.0.0.1`, you need to change `127.0.0.1` to the IP of your VM (`192.168.10.10`)
2. It would be http://todo.app not http://todo
3. Do you have port forwarding ? from your excerpt its commented, do you forward 80 to 8000, or do you have something running on the 8000 port of the VM ?

If you do localhost:8000, it assumes that you have forwarded port 80 from the VM to 8000 on the host while todo.app:8000 will directly point you to the VM and get what is running from the 8000 port of the VM.

4. You have a fixed IP address, so you can use `http://192.168.10.10` to access your laravel

Comment: Sorry i skipped .app in the question. it was todo.app:8000, but i have changed the point from 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.10.10 which is my VM's ip.
And I haven't forwarded any port but when i give command "vagrant up" there are few lines about doing port forwarding but hey still the problem is same and for some reason i don't know how but i'm again getting result at "localhost:8000" without doing "php artisan serve"